# Visual Basic Loop through query results

Tags: sql, vb.net, loops, listbox

I would like a code that loops through query results and displays them in a listbox in visual basic. What i have so far is a stored procedure, a listbox, and a button.

The stored procedure im calling is called "CycleCustomers" and the sql for that is as follows:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE CycleCustomers 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@p1 int

  AS
  BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT FirstName from tblCustomer where CustomerId = @p1
 END
```

The code i have on button click is as follows

```
 Dim dc = New DataTestDataContext
    Dim DealerCount As Int32
    DealerCount = 0
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()

    Do Until DealerCount = 10
        dc.CycleCustomers(DealerCount)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(dc.CycleCustomers(DealerCount).ReturnValue)
        DealerCount = DealerCount + 1
    Loop
```

When the button is clicked, my listbox returns 10 Zeros. What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: HERE IS THE CYCLECUSTOMERS FUNCTION

```
 <FunctionAttribute(Name:="dbo.CycleCustomers")>  _
Public Function CycleCustomers(<Parameter(DbType:="Int")> ByVal p1 As System.Nullable(Of Integer)) As ISingleResult(Of CycleCustomersResult1)
    Dim result As IExecuteResult = Me.ExecuteMethodCall(Me, CType(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod,MethodInfo), p1)
    Return CType(result.ReturnValue,ISingleResult(Of CycleCustomersResult1))
End Function
```

Comment: Show us the method `CycleCustomers` to see how it works.

Comment: You usually have a `SELECT` query and loop through that using a `DataReader`.

Comment: CycleCustomers Is a stored procedure and i put the code for it first

Comment: So its doing CycleCustomers(0) which is NULL
CycleCustomers(1) So SELECT FirstName from tblCustomer where CustomerId = 1 Which is 'Justin'
CycleCustomers(2) So SELECT FirstName from tblCustomer where CustomerId = 1 Which is 'Robert' etc..

Comment: I would try removing `.ReturnValue`. The `ReturnValue` of your Stored Procedure will always be 0. You are calling the Stored Procedure as a ,method from your DataContext. I don't know much about this approach but if you look in your DBML file it may show you what that method is supposed to return?

Comment: Return Type = (Auto Generated Type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534556(v=vs.110).aspx

What you are getting back is an ISingleResult of type CycleCustomerResult1, which is an IEnumerable. What you should be able do with Linq is something like:

```
Dim dc = New DataTestDataContext
Dim DealerCount As Int32
DealerCount = 0
ListBox2.Items.Clear()

Do Until DealerCount = 10
  Dim Customer = dc.CycleCustomers(DealerCount).SingleOrDefault()

  If (Not(Customer Is Nothing))
    ListBox2.Items.Add(Customer.FirstName)
  End If

  DealerCount = DealerCount + 1

Loop
```

I don't have Visual Studio to check this at the moment: also I generally use C#, so the precision of my VB is likely to be poor.

But the approach you have taken, in any case, seems very unorthodox. Ideally you would have a stored procedure that returns a set of rows and then iterate through that result adding to the listbox as you do so.

So for example a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CycleCustomers 
  AS
  BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT FirstName from tblCustomer 
 END
```

Then a function more like this

```
Dim Customers = dc.CycleCustomers()

For Each Customer In Customers
  ListBox2.Items.Add(Customer.FirstName)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i did it through LINQ to SQL and stored procedure but it works now. Here is the code for the button

```
 Dim number As Int32
    number = 1
    Dim dc = New DataTestDataContext

    Do Until number > dc.MaxCustomerId.First.CustomerId
        Dim Customers = From cust In dc.CycleCustomers(number) _
                      Where cust.CustomerId = number _
                      Select cust

        For Each cust In Customers
            ListBox2.Items.Add(cust.FirstName)

        Next
        number = number + 1
    Loop
```

And here is the stored procedure code

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE CycleCustomers 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@p1 int

   AS
   BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT CustomerId, FirstName from tblCustomer where CustomerId = @p1
 END
```

I made another stored procedure for the loop and it picks the largest Id number, the code for it is here

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE MaxCustomerId 

 AS
 BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT CustomerId 
  FROM tblCustomer 
 WHERE CustomerId=(SELECT max(CustomerId) FROM tblCustomer)

 END
```